# Docker postgresql client image

Tags: postgresql, docker

I want to deploy my app with Docker, but i don't have experience with postgresql and postgresql client images? Did anyone work with something similar?

I need some kind of client where I can see my database, tables and all the data, and I want to run everything with docker-compose.yml. If anyone has some .yml example with this setup also would be great.

Thx!

Answer (score 1):

For example you can use phppgadmin

docker image for phppgadmin -  https://hub.docker.com/r/zhajor/docker-phppgadmin/

docker-compose:

```
phpPgAdmin:
  container_name: phppgadmin
  image: fizix/docker-pgadmin:php-fpm-environment
  environment:
    - POSTGRESQL_HOST=postgres
    - POSTGRESQL_PORT=5432
    - POSTGRESQL_DEFAULT_DB=postgres
  ports:
    - 80:80
  links:
    - postgres
```